# Why is this Python Password Generator not working, nam is clearly defined

Tags: python, passwords

So, i am a new python coder and i am making a password generator but its saying nam is not defined.

This is my code:

```
    import random
    import string

    def gen():
    let1 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    nam = let1 + let2 + let3 + let4 + let5


    def num():
      num = '1234567890'
      number = random.choice(string.ascii_letters(num))

    pas = nam + nam + number + number + nam + number

    print(pas)
```

Comment: you have wrong indentions.

Comment: and nam is only clearly defined within the gen() function, but not outside. Try to identify the `scope` where nam is defined. In fact, number is also not defined outside of its function. In addition, none of your functions have return statements, which might mean nothing happens (In fact you haven't called your functions either so surely nothing happens).

Comment: Indentation is critical for understanding and executing Python programs. You need to post the actual indentation so we can tell what you're really doing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your indentation is a bit off (maybe just how you posted it?). However you also do not `return` any values from your functions, and therefore will not be able to access `nam` or `number` as you intend. You can adjust your script to return these variables and then change your definition of `pas` to call these functions. Something like:

```
import random
import string

def gen():
    let1 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    nam = let1 + let2 + let3 + let4 + let5
    return nam

def num():
    num = '1234567890'
    number = random.choice(num)
    return number

pas = gen() + gen() + num() + num() + gen() + num() # call functions, not variables within them

print(pas)
```

Resulting in: `hjvcwvmnlx79rnmdp7` being printed (when I ran it, your output will vary).

I suggest you review creating functions, and scope as the main errors were trying to access a local variable from a global scope, and not having your functions actually do anything (they are pretty useless without a `return`)

Answer (score 0):

There are `local variables` and `global variables`.

You create `nam` inside `gen()` and it is local variable which exists only inside `gen()` but not outside `gen()`.

But outside `gen()` you try to get value from `nam`

```
pas = nam + nam + number + number + nam + number
```

but Python doesn't know how to get value from variable which doesn't exist outside `gen()`.

Inside `gen()` you could use `return nam` to send value from function to outside function.

And then you can run `gen()` and assing returned value to variable. It can be `nam`.

```
nam = gen()
```

This way you create local variable `nam` which exists outside `get()` but not inside `get()`. For Python it will be two different variables.

You have the same problem with `number` in function `num()`

instead of `string.ascii_letters(num)` (which is incorrect) and `num` I will use `string.digits`

```
import random
import string

def gen():
    let1 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    nam = let1 + let2 + let3 + let4 + let5
    return nam

def num():
    number = random.choice(string.digits)
    return number 

nam = gen()
number = num()
pas = nam + nam + number + number + nam + number

print(pas)
```

To make it cleaner I change names inside functions - now it is only one `nam` and one `number`

```
import random
import string

def gen():
    let1 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    result = let1 + let2 + let3 + let4 + let5
    return result

def num():
    result = random.choice(string.digits)
    return result

nam = gen()
number = num()
pas = nam + nam + number + number + nam + number

print(pas)
```

I can also remove variables `result`

```
import random
import string

def gen():
    let1 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    let5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    return let1 + let2 + let3 + let4 + let5

def num():
    return random.choice(string.digits)

nam = gen()
number = num()
pas = nam + nam + number + number + nam + number

print(pas)
```